# Cloning empty form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, clone

I am still attempting to create blank fields that users can add on the fly. I am attempting to clone the following hidden template but I can't get it to add.

My HTML

```
 <div class="_100">
  <fieldset id="FieldBlank">
   <div id="readroot" class="hidden">

    <div class="_100">
     <div class="_50"> QA Sample ID:<input type="text" id="QASampleID" name="QASampleID"></div>
     <div class="_50" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
      <label>Collection Method</label><br />
        <input type="radio" id="radGrab1" value="Grab" name="Collection1" />
       <label for="radGrab1">Grab</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radEWI1" value="EWI" name="Collection1" />
       <label for="radEWI1">EWI</label></div>
    </div>

  <div class="_100">
   <div class="_40">    
    <label class="analysis-label" for="analysis">Analyte:</label>
     <select class="analysis" id="analysis" name="analysis" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value = "TN">TN</option>
      <option value = "TP,NO2+3">TP,NO2+3</option>
     </select></div>
    <div class="_30">   
     <label class="preserve-label" for="preserve">Preserved</label>
      <select class="select_preserve" id="preserve" name="preserve" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
       <option>Select</option>
       <option value = "HNO3">HNO&#8323;</option>
       <option value = "H2SO4">H&#8322;SO&#8324;</option>
      </select></div>
    <div class="_30"> 
      <label class="cool-label" for="cool">Cooled</label>
       <select class="select_cool" id="cool" name="cool" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">  
       <option>Select</option>
       <option value = "Ice">Ice</option>
       <option value = "Frozen">Frozen</option>
       <option value = "None">None</option>
      </select></div>
    </div>

   </div>                
  </fieldset>
 </div>   
   <button type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="moreFields" onclick="moreFields()">ADD FIELD BLANK</button>

 <hr /><div id="writeroot"> </div>
```

My javascript

```
var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}
```

I just cannot get it to work! Is it because this script is not jquery? It doesn't seem to be because it is hidden because when I unhide it the button still doesn't work to add the clones? I am so pulling my hair out right now. I need you help!

Comment: You tagged the question with jQuery but I see none.

Comment: if you are really using jQuery, you can just use http://api.jquery.com/clone/ but make sure you specify it's a deep clone. And just a note - don't use _ to begin a class name, some browsers don't like that.

Comment: there is no element with id "writeroot", just this <div id="writeroot"></div> it will work

Comment: Most of the form is jquery. I have sections that use the .clone but this captures the completed fields, I need empty firlds...Does the deep clone do this? if so how?

Comment: @AmitChotaliya I had the div id="writeroot" in there I just forgot to copy it over.

Comment: I just copied your code to notepad added a div with writeroot, it worked.

Comment: REALLY! I can't get it to work - can you check where I have the div in my code and tell me if it is in the wrong place or something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$("#readroot input").clone().appendTo("body"); // Or wherever you want to append them to
```

And, yeah, don't hide stuff manually. Use jQuery's toggle function instead:

```
$("#readroot").toggle(); // Or hide()
```

Comment: I had tried the hide/show but it only worked once and I need the ability to add multiple blanks

Comment: Now that I think about it, you don't really need to clone anything; do you? why don't you just use $('#writeroot').append($('<input/>')); to create new inputs as needed?